# Its my code please any one tell me why wordpress didn't create table in my database

Tags: wordpress

Its my code please any one tell me why wordpress didn't create table in my database:

```
function xc_create_all_tables(){

    global $wpdb;

    $cod = $wpdb->prefix."cod_system";
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $data = "CREATE TABLE  $cod (
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        picker_name varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        picker_add varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        picker_cell varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        picker_area varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        name varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        addd varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        cell varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        area varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        weight varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        pd_number varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        amount varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        status varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $data );

    $singlecod = $wpdb->prefix."singlecod_system";
    $charset_collate2 = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $data2 = "CREATE TABLE  $singlecod (
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        picker_name varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        picker_add varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        picker_cell varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        picker_area varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        name varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        addd varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        cell varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        area varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        weight varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        pd_number varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        amount varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        status varchar (255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate2;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $data2 );

}
```

Comment: Please check this help-topis to create a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this one to create a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Much probably you're calling this function wrongfully